# How to find and replace words containing particular characters in Lua?

Tags: lua

I have a string of “words”, like this: `fIsh mOuntain rIver`. The words are separated by a space, and I added spaces to the beginning and ending of the string to simplify the definition of a “word”.

I need to replace any words containing `A`, `B`, or `C`, with `1`, any words containing `X`, `Y`, or `Z` with `2`, and all remaining words with `3`, e.g.:

```
 the CAT ATE the Xylophone
```

First, replacing words containing `A`, `B`, or `C` with `1`, the string becomes:

```
 the 1 1 the Xylophone
```

Next, replacing words containing `X`, `Y`, or `Z` with `2`, the string becomes:

```
 the 1 1 the 2
```

Finally, it replaces all remaining words with `3`, e.g.:

```
 3 1 1 3 2
```

The final output is a string containing only numbers, with spaces between.

- The words might contain any kind of symbols, e.g.: `$5鱼fish` can be a word. The only feature defining the beginning and ending of words is the spaces.
- The matches are found in order, such that words which might possibly contain two matches, e.g. `ZebrA`, is simply replaced with `1`.
- The string is in UTF-8.

How can I replace all of the words containing these particular characters with numbers, and finally replace all remaining words with `3`?

Answer (score 7):

Try the following code:

```
function replace(str)
  return (str:gsub("%S+", function(word)
    if word:match("[ABC]") then return 1 end
    if word:match("[XYZ]") then return 2 end
    return 3
  end))
end

print(replace("the CAT ATE the Xylophone")) --> 3 1 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The [slnunicode](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/sln/slnunicode) module provides UTF-8 string functions.

Answer (score 0):

The `gsub` function/method in Lua is used to replace strings and to check out how times a string is found inside a string. `gsub(string old, string from, string to)`

```
local str = "Hello, world!"

newStr, recursions = str:gsub("Hello", "Bye"))
print(newStr, recursions)
```

> Bye, world!    1

newStr being "Bye, world!" because `from` was change to `to` and recursions being 1 because "Hello" (`from`) was only founds once in str.